# remove some lines in log file

Tags: shell, logging, text, text-processing

I have a big log file.

After removing the timestamp of each line, I sort it by `cat logfile | sort -u > logfile`, so that the logs are clean and organized as

```
failed to correct PL.ASBF..HHZ.2011.348 because of divided by zero
failed to correct PL.ASBF..HHZ.2011.349 because of divided by zero
failed to correct PL.ASBF..HHZ.2011.350 because of divided by zero
.
. (lines not shown here)
.
failed to correct PL.ASBF..HHZ.2015.364 because of divided by zero
failed to correct PL.ASBF..HHZ.2015.365 because of divided by zero
.
.
. (lines not shown here)
.
.
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2011.128 because of Illegal format
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2011.129 because of Illegal format
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2011.130 because of Illegal format
.
. (lines not shown here)
.
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2014.364 because of Illegal format
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2014.365 because of Illegal format
```

I can get the logged items (e.g. `PL.HSPB` in above example) by

```
grep -oE " [0-9A-Z]*\.[0-9A-Z]*" logfile | sort -u
```

However, I also want to known the date info and to make it clearer, I want to remove the intermedia lines. For example,

```
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2011.128 because of Illegal format
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2011.129 because of Illegal format
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2011.130 because of Illegal format
.
. (lines not shown here)
.
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2014.364 because of Illegal format
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2014.365 because of Illegal format
```

after removal becomes

```
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2011.128 because of Illegal format
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2014.365 because of Illegal format
```

i.e., for an item, only the first and last lines are kept (the digits are year and julian day).

Is there any shell command to make this with easy?

Comment: @shellter The date in the log file, such as `2014.365`, is 'year.jday'. No need to computer julian date from month and days.

Comment: Doah, I missed that the Y.Jday was in your original data. Good luck.

Comment: Just add another `grep` to your pipeline that is producing your current output? `grep "^failed to connect" logfile | grep -oE " [0-9A-Z]*\.[0-9A-Z]*" | sort -u` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Script:

```
$ cat hhz.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, re
from collections import OrderedDict

undateds = set()
firsts   = OrderedDict()
lasts    = OrderedDict()

while True:
  line = sys.stdin.readline()
  if line == '':
    break
  line = line.rstrip("\n")

  x = re.match("(.*HHZ\.)([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]+)( .*)", line)
  if x is None:
    continue

  before = x.group(1)
  during = x.group(2)
  after  = x.group(3)
  undated = re.sub("(.*HHZ\.)[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]+ (.*)", line, before+after)

  if not undated in firsts:
    firsts[undated] = line
  lasts[undated] = line

for undated in firsts:
  first = firsts[undated]
  last  = lasts[undated]
  print first
  if first != last:
    print last
```

Input:

```
$ cat hhz.dat
failed to correct PL.ASBF..HHZ.2011.348 because of divided by zero
failed to correct PL.ASBF..HHZ.2011.349 because of divided by zero
failed to correct PL.ASBF..HHZ.2011.350 because of divided by zero
failed to correct PL.ASBF..HHZ.2015.364 because of divided by zero
failed to correct PL.ASBF..HHZ.2015.365 because of divided by zero
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2011.128 because of Illegal format
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2011.129 because of Illegal format
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2011.130 because of Illegal format
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2011.130 because of Something else
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2014.364 because of Illegal format
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2014.365 because of Illegal format
```

Output:

```
$ hhz.py < hhz.dat
failed to correct PL.ASBF..HHZ.2011.348 because of divided by zero
failed to correct PL.ASBF..HHZ.2015.365 because of divided by zero
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2011.128 because of Illegal format
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2014.365 because of Illegal format
failed to correct PL.HSPB..HHZ.2011.130 because of Something else
```

- Group things by regexing out the date part. The `undated` is the uniqified name.
- Get first in group by doing an ordered-dict put if not already set.
- Get last in group by doing ordered-dict put unconditionally.
- Use `OrderedDict` to preserve input-file ordering (use `dict` if you don't want that)
- Check `first != last` to avoid printing the same thing twice in case there is only one item in the group